# Cambiar imagen al mostrar y ocultar un div con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un boton, que al pulsarlo hace que se muestre un div con jquery, y al volverlo a pulsar se vuelve a ocultar. Ese botón tiene una imagen, con la cual pretendo que cuando se muestre el div se cambie por otra, y al volver a darle al boton para cerrarla vuelva a cambiar a la imagen inicial.

He conseguido que al mostrar el div la imagen cambie, pero al ocultar el div, se queda la imagen cambiada y no vuelve a la anterior.

Mi código es el siguiente;

```
 <div class="filter-projects">
     <button  id="projects-filters">filters
        <img class="" id="img-filter" src="{{ asset('images/imgs/icons/icon-filter.svg') }}"/>
     </button>
 </div>

 <div class=" row col-md-12" id="filters">
 aqui va el contenido que muestro/oculto
 </div>
```

Y este sería el script

```
$(document).on('click', '#projects-filters', function () {
    $('#filters').toggle(100).css('display', 'flex');
    $("#img-filter").attr("src","images/imgs/icons/icon-filter-open.svg");

});
```

Comment: "{{ asset('images/imgs/icons/icon-filter.svg') }}" define lo mismo como "images/imgs/icons/icon-filter-open.svg" ?

Comment: @Duston si, es lo mismo, solo que el el blade de laravel los solemos poner así.

Answer (score 2):

de seguro debe haber una mejor opcion, pero yo a veces uso una variable global estado=false; cuando entras a la funcion y cambias la imagen pones esa variable a true solo tendria que evaluar con un if para determinar que foto poner.
algo asi:

```
let estado=false;

$(document).on('click', '#projects-filters', function () {
    if(estado == false){
        $('#filters').toggle(100).css('display', 'flex');
        $("#img-filter").attr("src","images/imgs/icons/icon-filter-open.svg");
        estado=true;
    } else{
        $('#filters').toggle(100).css('display', 'flex');
        $("#img-filter").attr("src","images/imgs/icons/icon-filter.svg");
        estado=false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Me funciona perfecto y realiza la funcionalidad que quería.

Comment: @BackName me alegro te funcione,aunque repito, de seguro ha de haber una opcion de codigo mas elegante, sin variables globales por ejemplo. Un Saludo!!